# How to ignore external list in case of lists in list(without using Numpy)

Tags: python, image-processing

I writing a function that its input is-  image_one, image_two, mask).
This function outputs a new image by calculating every new pixel according to the formula-

```
new_image[i][j] = round(image_one[i][j] x mask[i][j] + image_two[i][j] x (1 - mask[i][j]))
```

I wrote until now-

```
def image_plus_mask(image_one, image_two, mask):
    hight = len(image_one)
    width = len(image_one[0])
    new_image = [[0 for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(hight)]

    for i in range(hight):
        for j in range(width):
            new_image[i][j] = round((image_one[i][j] * mask[i][j]) + (image_two[i][j] * (1-mask[i][j])))
    return new_image
```

The function **dose** work on double lists.
For example:

Input-

```
image_plus_mask([[50, 50, 50]], [[200, 200, 200]], [[0, 0.5, 1]])
```

Output(as expected)-

```
[[200, 125, 50]]
```

The problem is that it is **not** working on 3 lists, and I need it to work on both- 2 and 3 lists.(by 2 I mean-[[]], by 3 I mean- [[[]]])

For example-

Input-

```
image_plus_mask([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]],
[[[250,250,250], [0,0,0]],[[250,250,100],[1,11,13]]],[[0,0.5]]*2))
```

Expected Output-

```
[[[250, 250, 250,], [2,2,3]], [[250, 250, 100], [6, 11, 12]]]
```

What can I do?

Comment: How do you get to the expected Output ?

Comment: By the formula I wrote in the beginning of the question.

Comment: yes, but then it is a mathematical problem, not a coding one. You shouldn't come to that expected output. Like D.Manasreh already said, the shapes don't fit together like you are using them.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but that is my problem , before I use the formula in my code I want to "fix" the images shape  to fit the mask.    This is why I want in case of 3 lists the function to "ignore" the external list. (The mask is always in the same shape- 2 lists).

Comment: you could make an if else statement where you check whether there are 3 lists or not. I'll post the edited function as an answer

Comment: A list of lists is not the right way to represent an image. Use NumPy, it’s not like you will learn more by not using it. You’ll just be solving problems that don’t need solving, and wasting time you could use to learn more important things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the comments said:

```
def image_plus_mask(image_one, image_two, mask):
    
    hight = len(image_one)
    width = len(image_one[0])
    
    #case: 3 lists
    if isinstance(image_one[0][0], (list,tuple)):
        depth = len(image_one[0][0])
        new_image = [[[0 for _ in range(depth)] for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(hight)]
        print(new_image)
        for i in range(hight):
            for j in range(width):
                for k in range(depth):
                    new_image[i][j][k] = round((image_one[i][j][k] * mask[i][j]) + (image_two[i][j][k] * (1-mask[i][j])))

    #case: 2 lists                
    else:
        new_image = [[0 for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(hight)]
        for i in range(hight):
            for j in range(width):
                new_image[i][j] = round((image_one[i][j] * mask[i][j]) + (image_two[i][j] * (1-mask[i][j])))
                
    return new_image
```

you need to adjust your shape of `new_image`. Look at your expected Output for 3 lists and look inside the function what you define for `new_image`. Couldn't work.

Output now:

```
res1 = image_plus_mask([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]],
[[[250,250,250], [0,0,0]],[[250,250,100],[1,11,13]]],[[0,0.5]]*2)

res2 = image_plus_mask([[50, 50, 50]], [[200, 200, 200]], [[0, 0.5, 1]]) 

print(res1)
[[[250, 250, 250], [2, 2, 3]], [[250, 250, 100], [6, 11, 12]]]

print(res2)
[[200, 125, 50]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mask has to be the same shape as your inputs.
If it is different then the `image_one[i][j] * mask[i][j]` will not work.

I highly suggest you using numpy arrays like this:

```
image1 = np.array([[50, 50, 50]])
image2 = np.array([[200, 200, 200]])
mask = np.array([[0, 0.5, 1]])

output = np.round(image1 * mask + image2 * (1 - mask))

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[[200. 125.  50.]]
```

If the shape of your inputs (images and mask) is consistent this will give what you want with any dimensions.

Comment: I want to learn the "hard" way , so I dint want to use Numpy.                                            There is a way to do that without Numpy?

Comment: Of course there is always a hard way to do things. Simply check the dimensions first. Then loop through each element in the images and the mask. Again make sure that your images and the mask have the same shape. In the example you provided the shape of your mask is not like the images.